# Reshape 3D numpy array with heterogeneous dimensions to 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

My data is 3D but only the third axis have a knowed dimension and I need to convert it to a 2D array.

Example:

```
input = 
[[[1, 2, 3]],

 [[4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]],

 [[1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]]]

input_reshaped = 
[[1, 2, 3],
 [4, 5, 6],
 [7, 8, 9],
 [1, 2, 3],
 [4, 5, 6],
 [7, 8, 9]]
```

So I have a 3D data in which the first and second dimensions are variable along my dataset and the third one is constant and previous knowed.

Every block in the input are also numpy arrays. I know that I could perform this using numpy.vstack and iterating over first dimension. But I would like to do this reshape in a pythonic way without explicity iterating over my data, if it's possible.

I already tried to perform a list compehension to get the first shape of each block and then sum these values and use it with reshape. Like this:

```
def myStack(a):
    lengths = [item.shape[0] for item in a]
    common_dim = a[0].shape[1]
    return a.reshape(np.sum(lengths), common_dim)
```

But with the input in the previous example, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 3 into shape (6,3)
```

Because the Python seen the input has a numy.array with shape (3,)

Any ideas?

Extra: If possible, making a back transformation in the above conditions would be really awesome!

Comment: How about `np.concatenate(inp axis=0)`?

Comment: What, **exactly** are you working with? Your example `input` array is *not an array*, it is a `list` object. Give us an example of your actual array. Note, you say your array is "3D", but if I use the array constructor on your `input` data it returns a one-dimensional array...

Comment: Hm, I don't think you have a choice but to use `np.vstack`. Or `np.concatenate` on a list of arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As recommended in the comments, `vstack` or `concatenate`:

```
In [320]: alist
Out[320]: [[[1, 2, 3]], [[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]]
In [321]: len(alist)
Out[321]: 3
```

Trying to make an array from the list just creates a 1d array of lists.  Not much help.  `reshape` won't work.

```
In [322]: np.array(alist)
Out[322]: 
array([list([[1, 2, 3]]), list([[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
       list([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])], dtype=object)
```

But `concatenate` works with a list of arrays (or array like objects):

```
In [323]: np.concatenate(alist, axis=0)
Out[323]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

`concatenate` will also work with `Out[322]` because it treats its input as a list even it is an array.

`vstack` is the same thing except it makes sure the subarrays are all 2d, which in this case they already are.

Comment: This resolve my problem. Thanks! But would be possible to do the reverse process? Because I'm "standarding" the data with the preprocessing module of sklearn, and I'll need to write back the data...

Comment: `np.split` (and variants) can split an array into a list of arrays.  Or just use your own list comprehension.